# How to have an ybar plot without frame?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I want to **remove the frame around a plot**, which usually works well with `axis lines = left`. However, something strange happens when trying this with `ybar`.

### Without axis lines=left

[image]

### With axis lines=left

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=tab]{data.tsv}\serialisations
\begin{axis}[
    ybar, xtick=data, xticklabels from table={\serialisations}{Name},
    axis lines=left, % remove for normal display
  ]
  \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y index=1]{\serialisations};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

*data.tsv*

```
Name    Value
A   2000
B   3000
C   4000
```

**How can I remove the frame, yet still have a correct graph?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ybar` in conjuction with `axis lines=left` seems to set `enlargelimits` to `false` or `0`.

You can use `axis lines=left, enlargelimits=.1` or `axis lines=left, enlargelimits=true` to restore the default value.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=tab]{data.tsv}\serialisations
\begin{axis}[
    ybar, xtick=data, xticklabels from table={\serialisations}{Name},
    axis lines=left,
    enlargelimits=.1 % <- adds 10% of the axis range on both sides
  ]
  \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y index=1]{\serialisations};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

It is also possible to change the x and the y limits separatly. You could use a dimension as `abs` value: `enlarge x limits={abs={1.5*\pgfplotbarwidth}}`. Additionaly you can enlarge only the upper limit of the y axis by `enlarge y limits={0.1,upper}` and define the lower y limit by `ymin=1000`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=tab]{data.tsv}\serialisations
\begin{axis}[
    ybar, xtick=data, xticklabels from table={\serialisations}{Name},
    axis lines=left,
    enlarge x limits={abs={1.5*\pgfplotbarwidth}},
    enlarge y limits={0.1,upper},
    ymin=1000
  ]
  \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y index=1]{\serialisations};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that indeed helps! Could you perhaps elaborate on why `enlargelimits` is necessary (i.e., why pgfplots doesn't do this automatically), and advise on how to choose the value? For larger plots, it seems that even smaller values of `enlargelimits` are needed. A possible drawback seems that my bar go floating above the x-axis. Maybe only `enlarge x limits` should be set?

Comment: I have changed my answer. But I do not know why `ybar` together with `axis lines=left` changes the `enlargelimits` option.

Comment: Great, very helpful answer!